# Find the domain of continuity and the domain of discontinuity of $\sqrt{x}-\frac{1}{x^2+x}$. What am I supposed to do exactly?

Tags: calculus, continuity

I am not entirely sure of what to do. I would find out where the function isn't continuous (which is x<=0) and the domain of continuity would be everything else (x>0). Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain of $f(x)=\sqrt{x}-\frac{1}{x^2+x}$ is $(0,\infty)$. As $f(x)$ does not exist for $x\le 0$ the question of discontinuity does not arise.

Comment: If you had a function that existed in R how would you do its domain of discontinuity?

Comment: @SilenceOnTheWire There cannot be a domain of discontinuity. Discontinuities occur only  at isolated points in the domain of a function.

Comment: @DrZafarAhmedDSc I believe you are wrong. The indicator function of the rationals is discontinuous over the entirety of the reals.

Comment: Let us discuss simple normal functions.

Answer (score 0):

The domain of the function is $D=\{ x \in \mathbb R: x>0\}$. The functon is continuous in each poit of $D$.